# Mixing antislip with porch paint

Tags: paint, exterior, porch

I would like to use this paint with antislip sand for some exterior concrete patios.

[image]

As I will be doing two coats, my question is, does antislip go in both coats or only the final one? I am not sure because I can see advantages to both ways. I am also using a bonding primer before these two coats, if it is pertinent to this question.

Comment: Do the manufacturer's instructions answer this? Personally I'd assume the top layer will experience wear, exposing the second layer, so I'd be inclined to add traction to both. YMMV.

Comment: This is more personal preference as to how much sand you want on the surface.